# Why do I get UTF8 format after I implement post call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, utf-8

I implement post call:

```
function SendMessage() {
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/PostEmail/Index",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {contact1: "ddd@mail.com" },
        success: function (result) { }
    });
}
```

I catch this call using this method:

```
public class PostEmailController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string contact1)
    {
        var contact2 = Request.Form;
        return View();
    }
}
```

After I implement a post call the variables equal to:

```
contact1= ddd@mail.com
contact2= ddd%40mail.com
```

Any idea why the sign "@" in contacts2 appeared in utf-8 format %40, while in contact1 I get the @ character?

Thank you in advane.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not utf8 encoded but urlencoded.

You simply have to urldecode contact2.

The post data is always transferred urlencoded as long as you don't use the multipart encoding. But typically the urldecoding is done by the Server application (e.g. Apache when you use php)